# Blazor Page receiving data from 3rd party website

Tags: blazor

What is the best practice in Blazor for receiving data from a third party website?  The website needs to receive some data from the third part, then have the user enter some data.  The best example I can think of is PayPal, you go to an online store, click pay with PayPal enter your login information then back to the online store.  I don't want the user to have the ability to modify the data, so having sensitive data as a URL parameter isn't an option.

My thought was to create a REST API that the third party would access.  It would receive the sensitive data, create all the database records for our apps, then create a unique ID that could be used as a parameter of the URL.

Is that good or is there a better way?

edit: Here are the basics of the Blazor app.  The user starts on the 3rd party website and selects what they are doing.  At some point what the user selects needs to be passed to my website.  This would be a `json` payload.  My App would then need to validate this payload and store it.  The user would then enter different information on our website.  Once the user is complete, the results need to be passed back to the original website.

Comment: I think you'll need to say exactly what you want to do, because there are different ways of doing this depending on exactly what you need.

Comment: @PeterMorris gave a bit more information

Comment: Is this a user flow you are describing? They visit site X, enter info, are redirected to your site to enter more info, and then go back to site X with the combined information?

Comment: Simplifying it yes.

Comment: Server-side Blazor, WebAssembly hosted in ASP.NET MVC, or standalone WebAssembly?

Comment: @PeterMorris this would. W server-side

Comment: Presumably then the site code http post to your site. The receiving page could create a C# object and pass it as a parameter to your App.razor component in the cshtml. Would that work?